# How do you make a user a member for a SharePoint site?

Tags: 2007

I'm some kind of admin on my sharepoint site, but not the big kahuna who runs it all.

I can add users and groups and set permissions within my site.

What I can't figure out how to do is actually make a user a member, so that when they use the My Links dropdown, they'll be able to see the sites I run as one of the options (that arise from the My SharePoint Sites option).

How do you make, and in fact even tell that a user is a member (in 2007)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to setup the groups, and you have to add the user to the group that is setup as "Members of this Site".

To setup the groups or to see what group is already setup for the "Members of this Site" group, go to people and groups, settings, then set up groups.

Comment: Well, I guess I got it done that way, but it didn't really work, I still can't get the link to work for members.  I can't believe they didn't integrate SharePoint fully with AD, quite frustrating.  thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have your indexing working?  I think the my links integration requires having a SSP and indexing setup correctly.